# How do you select individual groups of 1000 objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, object

At first I was trying to do this :

```
 Photo.find(:all, :conditions => ["id < 2000 AND id > 999"])
```

But then I realized that this isn't necessarily 1000 objects. How do I select exactly a thousand objects. So that I can run a process that works 1,000 objects at a time. Such as this..

```
Photo.find(:all, :conditions => ["id < 2000 AND id > 999"]).each{|instance| instance.photo.reprocess!(:tiny_thumb) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use `:limit` and `:offset`:

```
# First chunk
Photo.find(:all, :order => :id, :limit => 1000)

# Second chunk
Photo.find(:all, :order => :id, :limit => 1000, :offset => 1000)
```

You need to include the `:order` to ensure consistent results, otherwise the entries won't necessarily come out in the same order that will mess up your chunking.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic!! I never knew these commands. Out of random curiosity is there a way to process them backwards?

Comment: @Trip: You could `:order => 'id desc'` to sort them in the reverse order or find out how many there are and start the `:offset` 1000 from the end and decrease it for each chunk. The `:offset` and `:limit` things (like much of AR) originate in SQL, using AR is a lot easier if you know SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_in_batches`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

with a `:batch_size` of 1000, which also happens to be the default.